# Table formatting with tabularx?

Tags: tabularx

I am trying to format the table to obtain the one in the picture. However, the result is less than satisfactory, could you please help me with tabularx enviroment?[image]

```
\begin{table}[]
    \centering
    \caption{Value of the force local maximums (F\textsubscript{i} and F\textsubscript{Q}) and magnitude of the associated load drops observed in the load-displacement curves of impacted and indented LTHIN\textsubscript{LVI}, LV1\textsubscript{LVI} and LV2\textsubscript{LVI} specimens, $\pm$ refers to the standard deviation between experiments.}
    \label{Table3pD}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ccccccc}
        \hline
        Material & \multicolumn{6}{c}{Test}                                                                          \\ \cline{2-7} 
        & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Impact at 10 J} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Impact at 14 J} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{QSI} \\ \cline{2-7} 
        & F\textsubscript{i} (kN)              & Load drop (\%)       & F\textsubscript{i} (kN)              & Load drop (\%)         & F\textsubscript{Q} (kN)      & Load drop (\%)   \\ \hline
        LTHIN\textsubscript{LVI}    & 3.24 $\pm$ 0.02       & 19.75 $\pm$ 0.55       & 3.41 $\pm$ 0.25       & 22.80 $\pm$ 1.40       & 3.32     & Multiple     \\
        LV1\textsubscript{LVI}      & 3.19 $\pm$ 0.04       & 14.64 $\pm$ 2.55       & 3.24 $\pm$ 0.22       & 11.34 $\pm$ 4.46       & 3.10     & Multiple     \\
        LV2\textsubscript{LVI}      & 3.51 $\pm$ 0.15       & 8.17 $\pm$ 2.36        & 3.95 $\pm$ 0.51       & 10.80 $\pm$ 1.28       & None     & None         \\ \hline
        %   \end{tabular}
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Why are you using `tabularx` if you have no `X` columns?  This table looks like it would be fine without using `tabularx` at all. Also you should be using `booktabs` for its rules. (And it's helpful to post compilable documents on the site, instead of code fragments.)

Comment: Thank you! Could you please provide an example (still very new in Latex)

Comment: Maybe you could elaborate on why you are not satisfied with the result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a juxtaposition of three possible solutions: with `tabularx`, with `tabular`, and with `tabular*`. Since there's no need for automatic line breaks in any cells, using `tabularx` seems like overkill. You should choose between either the `tabular` and the `tabular*` solution.

What I would really recommend you do (and what's implemented in all three solutions below) is to use the line-drawing macros of the `booktabs` package instead of `\hline` and `\cline`. I would also provide a bit more structure to the header material, say by placing information about units of measurement on lines of their own. Finally, consider using the `\SI` and `\si` macros of the `siunitx` package to typeset scientific units (with and without numbers).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry} % choose page parameters suitably
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,siunitx,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage[skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption} % optional

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption{Table with \texttt{tabularx}} \label{tab:tabularx}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} l *{6}{C}@{}}
\toprule
Material & \multicolumn{6}{c@{}}{Test} \\ 
\cmidrule(l){2-7} 
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{Impact at \SI{10}{\joule}} 
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{Impact at \SI{14}{\joule}} 
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{QSI} \\ 
\cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-5} \cmidrule(l){6-7} 
& $F_i$ & Load drop & $F_i$ & Load drop & $F_Q$ & Load drop \\ 
& (\si{\kilo\newton}) & (\%) & (\si{\kilo\newton}) & (\%) & (\si{\kilo\newton}) & (\%) \\
\midrule
LTHIN\textsubscript{LVI}    & 3.24 $\pm$ 0.02       & 19.75 $\pm$ 0.55       & 3.41 $\pm$ 0.25       & 22.80 $\pm$ 1.40       & 3.32     & Multiple     \\
LV1\textsubscript{LVI}      & 3.19 $\pm$ 0.04       & 14.64 $\pm$ 2.55       & 3.24 $\pm$ 0.22       & 11.34 $\pm$ 4.46       & 3.10     & Multiple     \\
LV2\textsubscript{LVI}      & 3.51 $\pm$ 0.15       & 8.17 $\pm$ 2.36        & 3.95 $\pm$ 0.51       & 10.80 $\pm$ 1.28       & None     & None  \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\bigskip\bigskip

\caption{Table with \texttt{tabular}} \label{tab:tabular}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{} l *{6}{c} @{}}
\toprule
Material & \multicolumn{6}{c@{}}{Test} \\ 
\cmidrule(l){2-7} 
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{Impact at \SI{10}{\joule}} 
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{Impact at \SI{14}{\joule}} 
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{QSI} \\ 
\cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-5} \cmidrule(l){6-7} 
& $F_i$ & Load drop & $F_i$ & Load drop & $F_Q$ & Load drop \\ 
& (\si{\kilo\newton}) & (\%) & (\si{\kilo\newton}) & (\%) & (\si{\kilo\newton}) & (\%) \\
\midrule
LTHIN\textsubscript{LVI}    & 3.24 $\pm$ 0.02       & 19.75 $\pm$ 0.55       & 3.41 $\pm$ 0.25       & 22.80 $\pm$ 1.40       & 3.32     & Multiple     \\
LV1\textsubscript{LVI}      & 3.19 $\pm$ 0.04       & 14.64 $\pm$ 2.55       & 3.24 $\pm$ 0.22       & 11.34 $\pm$ 4.46       & 3.10     & Multiple     \\
LV2\textsubscript{LVI}      & 3.51 $\pm$ 0.15       & 8.17 $\pm$ 2.36        & 3.95 $\pm$ 0.51       & 10.80 $\pm$ 1.28       & None     & None  \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\bigskip\bigskip

\caption{Table with \texttt{tabular*}} \label{tab:tabular*}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l *{6}{c}}
\toprule
Material & \multicolumn{6}{c}{Test} \\ 
\cmidrule(l){2-7} 
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{Impact at \SI{10}{\joule}} 
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{Impact at \SI{14}{\joule}} 
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{QSI} \\ 
\cmidrule{2-3} \cmidrule{4-5} \cmidrule{6-7} 
& $F_i$ & Load drop & $F_i$ & Load drop & $F_Q$ & Load drop \\ 
& (\si{\kilo\newton}) & (\%) & (\si{\kilo\newton}) & (\%) & (\si{\kilo\newton}) & (\%) \\
\midrule
LTHIN\textsubscript{LVI}    & 3.24 $\pm$ 0.02       & 19.75 $\pm$ 0.55       & 3.41 $\pm$ 0.25       & 22.80 $\pm$ 1.40       & 3.32     & Multiple     \\
LV1\textsubscript{LVI}      & 3.19 $\pm$ 0.04       & 14.64 $\pm$ 2.55       & 3.24 $\pm$ 0.22       & 11.34 $\pm$ 4.46       & 3.10     & Multiple     \\
LV2\textsubscript{LVI}      & 3.51 $\pm$ 0.15       & 8.17 $\pm$ 2.36        & 3.95 $\pm$ 0.51       & 10.80 $\pm$ 1.28       & None     & None  \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Very helpful as well!

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to use `tabularx` for this type of table. Here's your example using `booktabs` for nicer spacing and rules, and the `caption` package to give you more control over the caption (in this case it automatically adds some space between the caption and the table.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[]
    \centering
    \caption{Value of the force local maximums (F\textsubscript{i} and F\textsubscript{Q}) and magnitude of the associated load drops observed in the load-displacement curves of impacted and indented LTHIN\textsubscript{LVI}, LV1\textsubscript{LVI} and LV2\textsubscript{LVI} specimens, $\pm$ refers to the standard deviation between experiments.}
    \label{Table3pD}
    \begin{tabular}{ccccccc}
        \toprule
        Material & \multicolumn{6}{c}{Test}                                                                          \\ \cmidrule{2-7} 
        & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Impact at 10 J} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Impact at 14 J} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{QSI} \\ \cmidrule{2-7} 
        & F\textsubscript{i} (kN)              & Load drop (\%)       & F\textsubscript{i} (kN)              & Load drop (\%)         & F\textsubscript{Q} (kN)      & Load drop (\%)   \\
        \midrule
        LTHIN\textsubscript{LVI}    & 3.24 $\pm$ 0.02       & 19.75 $\pm$ 0.55       & 3.41 $\pm$ 0.25       & 22.80 $\pm$ 1.40       & 3.32     & Multiple     \\
        LV1\textsubscript{LVI}      & 3.19 $\pm$ 0.04       & 14.64 $\pm$ 2.55       & 3.24 $\pm$ 0.22       & 11.34 $\pm$ 4.46       & 3.10     & Multiple     \\
        LV2\textsubscript{LVI}      & 3.51 $\pm$ 0.15       & 8.17 $\pm$ 2.36        & 3.95 $\pm$ 0.51       & 10.80 $\pm$ 1.28       & None     & None         \\ 
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @Santi You're welcome. But you should look at the other answers too. I agree with both Mico and leandriis that using `siunitx` is a good idea for any table that has numerical data in it.

Answer (score 5):

Here is an approach similar to [Alan Munn's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/485928/134144) and [Mico's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/485929/134144) but I have also used `S` type columns from `siunitx` in order to improve the alignment of the numbers (especially in the third column).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{separate-uncertainty}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[]
    \centering
    \caption{Value of the force local maximums (F\textsubscript{i} and F\textsubscript{Q}) and magnitude of the associated load drops observed in the load-displacement curves of impacted and indented LTHIN\textsubscript{LVI}, LV1\textsubscript{LVI} and LV2\textsubscript{LVI} specimens, $\pm$ refers to the standard deviation between experiments.}
    \label{Table3pD}
    \begin{tabular}{c
                    S[table-format=1.2(3)]
                    S[table-format=2.2(3)]
                    S[table-format=1.2(3)]
                    S[table-format=2.2(3)]
                    S[table-format=1.2]
                    c}
        \toprule
        Material & \multicolumn{6}{c}{Test}                                                                          \\ \cmidrule{2-7} 
        & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Impact at 10 J} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Impact at 14 J} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{QSI} \\ \cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-5} \cmidrule(l){6-7} 
        & {F\textsubscript{i} (\si{\kilo\newton})}             & {Load drop (\%)}       & {F\textsubscript{i} (\si{\kilo\newton})}              & {Load drop (\%)}         & {F\textsubscript{Q} (\si{\kilo\newton})}      & {Load drop (\%)}   \\
        \midrule
        LTHIN\textsubscript{LVI}    & 3.24 \pm 0.02       & 19.75 \pm 0.55       & 3.41 \pm 0.25       & 22.80 \pm 1.40       & 3.32     & Multiple     \\
        LV1\textsubscript{LVI}      & 3.19 \pm 0.04       & 14.64 \pm 2.55       & 3.24 \pm 0.22       & 11.34 \pm 4.46       & 3.10     & Multiple     \\
        LV2\textsubscript{LVI}      & 3.51 \pm 0.15       & 8.17 \pm 2.36        & 3.95 \pm 0.51       & 10.80 \pm 1.28       & {None}     & None         \\ 
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I propose the following code, with packages `geometry (to have more decent margins, if you don't need marginal notes`, `siunitx` for the alignment of numbers and `booktabs`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry} 
\usepackage{tabularx, multirow, caption, booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htb]
    \centering\sisetup{table-number-alignment=center, separate-uncertainty, table-align-uncertainty=false}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4.5pt}
 \caption{Value of the force local maximums (F\textsubscript{i} and F\textsubscript{Q}) and magnitude of the associated load drops observed in the load-displacement curves of impacted and indented LTHIN\textsubscript{LVI}, LV1\textsubscript{LVI} and LV2\textsubscript{LVI} specimens, $\pm$ refers to the standard deviation between experiments.}
 \label{Table3pD}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{X*{2}{S[table-format=1.2(1)]S[table-format=2.2(2)]}S[table-format=1.2]c}
        \toprule
 \multirow{5}{=}{Material} & \multicolumn{6}{c}{Test} \\ \cmidrule(lr){2-7}
 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Impact at 10 J} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Impact at 14 J} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{QSI} \\ \cmidrule(lr){2-7}
 & {F\textsubscript{i} (kN)} & {Load drop (\%)} &{ F\textsubscript{i} (kN)} & {Load drop (\%)} & {F\textsubscript{Q} (kN)} & Load drop (\%) \\ \midrule
 LTHIN\textsubscript{LVI} & 3.24 (2)& 19.75(55) & 3.41(25) & 22.80(140)
  & 3.32 & Multiple \\ \addlinespace
 LV1\textsubscript{LVI} & 3.19 (4)& 14.64(255) & 3.24(22) & 11.34(446)
   & 3.10 & Multiple \\ \addlinespace
 LV2\textsubscript{LVI} & 3.51 (15) & 8.17(236)& 3.95(51) & 10.80(128)
   & {None} & None \\ \bottomrule
        % \end{tabular}
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]